# Change Authorize.net AcceptUI.js "data-paymentOptions" after load

Tags: jquery, authorize.net

I'm trying to work around a really silly issue with authorize.net's acceptui. The payment button looks like this:

```
<button type="button"
        id="payment_button"
        class="AcceptUI btn btn-success"
        data-billingAddressOptions='{"show":false, "required":false}' 
        data-apiLoginID="loginId" 
        data-clientKey="clientKey"
        data-acceptUIFormBtnTxt="Submit" 
        data-acceptUIFormHeaderTxt=""
        data-paymentOptions='{"showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": true}' 
        data-responseHandler="paymentResponseHandler">
            Get Token
    </button>
```

I need to change `data-paymentOptions='{"showCreditCard": true, "showBankAccount": true}'` AFTER load to turn off either option. Can this be done?

I tried:

```
 $( ".AcceptUI" ).data().paymentoptions.showCreditCard = false
```

This sets the paymentOption of show credit card to false, but it still loads the credit card option.

Comment: Changing the `data` attribute after the library has been initialised on the button will most likely have no effect. You either need to call a method to update the options of the library, or you need to re-initialise the library on the button entirely. Refer to their documentation for more info

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'd love to refer to their documentation but I can't find anything detailed, just a walkthrough.

Comment: In this page of [their docs](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html#Integrating_the_Hosted_Payment_Information_Form) it states: `If you are building your page dynamically, be sure that your page loads the Accept JavaScript library after the button is defined. For the library to correctly interface with the button, the button must already exist in the DOM when the library is loaded.` Therefore you cannot change any of the button's properties after accept.js has been loaded. What you're trying to do isn't possible with this library.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is only because I'm trying to work around the most ridiculous of problems, that it says "credit card" on the payment screen if both options are true.

Comment: I'd suggest contacting their support then, as from that issue, and the way the JS is structured, the whole thing seems poorly thought through.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. I'm just going to close this question, since it doesn't seem possible.